# I want to start an activity from my application's onCreate() method behind my main activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I want to start an activity located in my installer application behind my main screen activity and I call it using:

```
public class MYAPP extends Application {

    public void onCreate() {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        ComponentName cName = new ComponentName("com.example.installer",
                "com.example.installer.MainActivity");
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_PREVIOUS_IS_TOP);
        intent.setComponent(cName);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

But I get the `MainActivity` in the foreground and I don't want that. I want to keep my application main activity on top of it.

How can I do that?

Comment: what is the purpose of what you trying to do? there is no point in launching activity if you don't wont it upfront.

Comment: If you don't want to show an `Activity` then it should be a background task such as `sevice` or `asynctask`

Comment: You can call the intent for your `MainActivity` in the `onCreate()` of second class.

Comment: because I have a service that will work when I am updating my application and it is located in the com.example.installer application and the service don't work until  one of its program activity launched